# RX2. How to react on nothing emitted after x seconds?

Tags: java, rx-java2

Despite that my question seems very common I haven't found any *nice* solution to this. The situation, of course, is solvable, but I want to solve it in more RX way, if you know what I mean.

**The situation**

I have an `Observable` that emits some events. What I want is to subscribe for next upcoming event, and do something, **if** there will be no events emitted for 1 second. So, if something is emitted - call method `doSomething()`. If nothing was emitted during 1 second, call method `doSomething()`.

**Possible solution**

One of the possible solutions is to create `Completable.timer(1000)`, subscribe for both, and wait for first to emit / complete. Something like `Observable.combineLatest` except I don't have to wait both, but just first event to arrive. But I haven't found such functionality in RX2 also.

**Please advice**

Please advice solution for both situations, if possible, is there a way to set a waiting delay for next emitted item, or to pick first emitted from several observables?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you try to achieve here. Do you want a keep-alive like event which is merged into the main flow? Do you want to execute an action after the source didn't produce an item without cancelling the source?

Comment: @akarnokd, the main criteria is described in the question. I don't care about the source, and I don't want to keep anything alive.

Comment: Sounds like you need [`Observable.ambArray()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#ambArray-io.reactivex.ObservableSource...-).

Comment: @akarnokd, looks like it will fit, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Observable.ambArray()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#ambArray-io.reactivex.ObservableSource...-).

Thanks to the @akarnokd comment